# Bash. Команда send не найдена, invalid command name "telnet"

Tags: linux, bash

Всем привет, написал скрипт, который должен по идее в telnet включать логи и слушать их:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/expect
expect -c 'telnet localhost 4242';
send -- "logging enable";
echo "Update finished!"
```

Но при запуске этого скрипта получаю:

> invalid command name "telnet"
>   
>  while executing
>   
> "telnet localhost 4242"
>   
> ./logtelnet.sh: line 4: send: command not found
>   
> Update finished!

Что я делаю не так? подскажите плиз

Comment: send  не может найти (send: command not found) . установите пакет, который содержит send

Comment: удалите первую строку. или явно вызывайте программу `expect`: `$ expect logtelnet.sh`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor вызов send является внутренней командой expect, а в данном случае выполняется как отдельная команда оболочки баш, в связи с этим и получилась такая ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте следующую команду:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

expect -c 'spawn telnet localhost 4242;
    expect "Connected" {send -- "logging enable\r"};
; interact'
```

По поводу двух интерпритаторов в вашем примере

> #!/bin/bash
>   #!/bin/expect

Вторая строка воспринимается как обычный комментарий

Comment: №#@#!$, опять не заметил что тема 17 года...

Comment: Ну всеравно держи плюсик)

Answer (score 0):

Я не помню точно, как выглядит начальный диалог telnet, но то, что вы хотите сделать, должно начинаться както-так:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn telnet localhost 4242
while 1 { expect {
  "Login*: "   {send "Ivanov\r"}
  "Password:" {send "IvanovPassword\r"}
  "> "     {break}
  "Unable"    {send_user "Нет доступа к locakhost.\r"; exit 1}
  timeout     {send_user "Время ожидания ответа истекло."\r"; exit 2}
}}
```

Вместо строк "Login*: " и "Password:" поставьте то, что на самом деле выдаёт telnet